# Is Maven Eclipse plugin working correctly?

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, m2eclipse, weblogic12c

I am using `Eclipse` (Kelper or Juno) with built-in **Maven** support. When setting up a bigger project structure (having a war project that references several simple Java-Projects) I am facing some unwanted classpath behaviour at runtime (using the **Oracle Weblogic Server Tools** to run the application within a **Weblogic Server**):

Let's say the war project refences `comp1` and `comp2` as Maven dependencies that are set up as Eclipse projects. And let us assume that `comp1` has a dependency to `comp3-1.0.0` whereas `comp2` has a dependency to `comp3-1.2.0`.

I am getting both `comp3` versions at runtime. When code from `comp1` is executed it will use `comp3-1.0.0` and when code from `comp2` is executed it will use `comp3-1.2.0`.

As all code is part of the same web application I would expect that also for `comp2` the code from `comp3-1.2.0` is executed. This is in contrast to the behaviour when buidling a war file and running that directly in a web server. In that case only one `comp3` would become part of the war file wouldn't it?

Is this wanted behaviour or is this a bug in the Eclipse Plugin or the Weblogic Server Tools. How can I circumvent this behaviour?